# Pick a file without file name using url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

How can i pick the file in a folder without giving file name using htaccess, like,

www.domainname/folder/

while the actual link is

www.domainname/folder/filename.pdf

(NOTE) I have only one pdf file in the folder.

Comment: I want to write this url www.domainname/folder/ in browser to pick the pdf file. one pdf in one folder.

I tried this,
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) loader.php?file=http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

System will send it to loader.php then i can decide which folder and which file. Same thing is working in one server but in 2nd server its not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do not need htaccess for this. Only use php to list the existing file in that directory. Put the php code in index.php

```
$files1 = scandir($dir);
print_R($files1);
```

There is no problem to solve. index.php is default file in most webservers. If the file is always called the same that is in the directory just create a file named index.php in the directory and pick the file?

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to create a .htaccess file in the www.domainname.com/folder directory and add `DirectoryIndex filename.pdf` to it.

If that doesn't work, you could make an index.php file in the directory and put:

```
<?php
   header( 'Location: filename.pdf' ) ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it with .htaccess or a PHP based solution, you can create a simple `index.html` file with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.example.com/somefile.pdf" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- optional, just to have something in the body -->
    <p><a href='http://www.example.com/somefile.pdf'>download me!</a></p>
</body></html>
```

Explaination: If the server has autoindexing activated (which most have), it will automatically handle files like `index.html` or `index.php` as index files for the directory and deliver their content when only the folder name is requested.

So what we use here is an “invisible” `index.html` in combination with a meta-redirect, to cause an instant redirect.

Small disadvantage: The client will see the page content for a brief moment. If you don't like it, use a server-side solution. But you could as well show a little text like “you are being redirected to the document, please wait a second …”.